# What HTTP verb should be used for oversized requests with GET semantics?

Tags: api, rest, http, architecture

Consider that you need to design an API that allows one to compute HMAC signatures over arbitrary messages. In REST world, it would likely be few endpoints, like:

> `POST /messages/` — to create new plaintext message.
>
> `GET /messages/123/signature` — to get HMAC for message #123. This is idempotent and pure, as signature will be always the same.
>
> `DELETE /messages/123` — to remove that message after signing.

But what if you don't like the idea of storing messages as plaintext in-between calls? As signing function is idempotent, pure, and can be cached, `GET /sign/?message=...` would seem to be a good choice. But there is restriction on maximum length of `GET` request, and average size of message to be signed is 40KiB.

Then, is it `POST`? But POST is not idempotent, while this method is.

Then, is it `PUT`? What verb should be then used instead of `GET`?

Answer (score 0):

Tough question as it's about how to bend the REST principles to overcome a technical issue, so the answers will probably be opinionated.

Personally, I would use a PUT, just because, as you said, it's idempotent..

If you're doing the call form another server, you probably can configure your webserver to accept longer GET requests (this doesn't apply if you're calling from a web browser).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use POST because it's the de facto "catch-all" method for anything slightly out of convention, e.g. something like `POST /messages/signature`, `POST /messages?view=signature`. A POST without an ID already makes it clear something's different, whereas a PUT would look too much like an actual call to create a resource.